# Use Taylor series to compute $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{1}{\sin(x)}- \frac{1}{x} \right) $

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

Use Taylor series to solve $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{1}{\sin(x)}- \frac{1}{x} \right) $$

This equals $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)!}{x^{2n+1}(-1)^{n+1}} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(-x+1)^n} \right)$$

I am unsure how to proceed. I tried writing out the first few terms, but nothing seemed to cancel.

Comment: Where did the formulae on the last line appear from???

Comment: Perhaps you might want to try something a little less wild such as considering the quotient ${x - \sin x \over x \sin x}$? Develop the Taylor of the numerator and demoninator.

Comment: @copper.hat The first sum is the inverse of the sin taylor polynomial and the second sum is derived from the sum of a geometric series

Comment: The function $x \mapsto {1 \over \sin x}$ does not have a Taylor series. The Taylor series of the reciprocal is not the reciprocal of the Taylor series. The second series converges to $1-{1 \over x}$, not ${1 \over x}$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure how you got your formula. Using just the first $2$ terms of the Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ (you actually only need just $1$ term, as shown in some of the other answers, but I thought using $2$ may help to better see what is going on), such as given in [Trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions), and as suggested in [copper.hat](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/27978/copper-hat)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588661/use-taylor-series-to-solve-lim-x-to-0-frac1sinx-frac1x#comment7378192_3588661), you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)} - \frac{1}{x}\right) & = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x - \sin(x)}{x\sin(x)}\right) \\
& = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x - \left(x - \frac{x^3}{6} + O(x^5)\right)}{x\left(x - \frac{x^3}{6} + O(x^5)\right)}\right) \\
& = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{x^3}{6} - O(x^5)}{x^2 - \frac{x^4}{6} + O(x^6)}\right) \\
& = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{x}{6} - O(x^3)}{1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + O(x^4)}\right) \\
& = \frac{0}{1} \\
& = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Comment: Could you explain how the last limit reduced to $\frac{0}{1}$? As written, the $O(x^4)$ term in the denominator could be strictly of lower order than $x^4$ (even a constant is allowed), so that the $O(x^3)$ in the numerator could dominate and the whole ratio could blow up.  Perhaps this would be fixed if you wrote $\Theta(x^4)$ instead of  $O(x^4)$ ? Or used a suitable small o in the numerator?

Comment: @YiboYang With the [Big $O$ Formal Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), $f(x) = O(x^4)$ means for all $\lambda \gt 0$, there's an $M \gt 0$ such that for all $0 \lt \lvert x \rvert \lt \lambda$, then $\lvert f(x) \rvert \le Mx^4$. Thus, as $x \to 0$, we have $O(x^4) \to 0$. I'm not sure what you mean by it being "strictly of lower order", and the only constant that may be allowed is $0$. Note in the numerator, both $\frac{x}{6}$ and $O(x^3)$ go to $0$, so the numerator overall goes to $0$. Similarly in the denominator, it goes to $1$. ...

Comment: @YiboYang (cont.) This uses that if $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = g_{0}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}h(x) = h_{0}$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}(g(x) \pm h(x)) = g_{0} \pm h_{0}$ and, if $h_{0} \neq 0$, then also $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} = \frac{g_0}{h_0}$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, that makes sense. Somehow I forgot about the 1 in the denominator, and lumped together the whole $1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + O(x^4)$ as $O(x^4)$, which led me to think $\lim \frac{O(x^3)}{O(x^4)}$ would be undetermined.

Comment: Actually, I think my main confusion was about step "(1)" (the second to last limit), where you essentially reduced $\lim \frac{O(x^5)}{O(x^6)} $ to $\lim \frac{O(x^3)}{O(x^4)} $ by dividing by $x^2$. Could you also explain this? I agree that $\frac{O(x^5)}{x^2} = O(x^3)$, and $\frac{O(x^6)}{x^2} = O(x^4)$, but I'm not sure you can just take the ratio.   Sorry I'm still getting used to the big O small o stuff.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment about step (1): Would it be more correct to write $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{x^3}{6} - O(x^5)}{x^2 - \frac{x^4}{6} + O(x^6)}\right)  \leq \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{x^3}{6} - O(x^5)}{x^2 - \frac{x^4}{6} }\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{x}{6} - O(x^3)}{1- \frac{x^2}{6} }\right) $, so we only reduce the big O in the numerator?

Comment: @YiboYang You wrote that I "essentially reduced $\lim\frac{O(x^5)}{O(x^6)}$ to $\lim\frac{O(x^3)}{O(x^4)}$ by dividing by $x^2$". This is incorrect. Since $x \to 0$, then before the division, the dominant term in the numerator is $\frac{x^3}{6}$ (i.e., $O(x^3)$) and in the denominator it's $x^2$ (i.e., $O(x^2)$). After the division, the numerator dominant term is then $\frac{x}{6}$ (i.e., $O(x)$) and denominator dominant term is $1$ (i.e., $O(1)$). When dealing with limits involving fractions, *only* the dominant term in the numerator and denominator end up determining the result.

Comment: @YiboYang As for your second comment about your first, I believe it's actually less correct to write what you did. The $\le$ between your first $2$ terms is technically correct, but misleading as the $O(x^6)$ term goes to $0$ so the limit will always be equal, i.e., the $\lt$ part of $\le$ is superfluous. I hope this answers your concerns. If not, I suggest you post a question with what you still don't understand as using comments here is not a particularly good way to resolve what has not yet been fully clarified for you.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation John! I was really just curious about how you could simultaneously reduce the $O(x^5)$ and $O(x^6)$ terms in the numerator and denominator by $x^2$, but just asked it in a confusing way (of course, the numerator in (1) is $O(x^3)$, not just $O(x^5)$). I think the reason this works is simply that the limit ultimately exists, and limit laws apply. A counter-example would be $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x+O(x)}{O(x^2)}$; "canceling" out $x$ gives $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1+O(1)}{O(x)} = \infty$, but this may be wrong depending on the actual functions hiding behind big Os.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly believe that you don't have to use the WHOLE Taylor Series, but just the firs terms.

You know that

$$\sin(x) \approx x + O(x^3)$$ as $x\to 0$ hence just substitute in the $\sin(x)$ term to get:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x}\right) = 0$$

Comment: I agree that this is likely the far simpler solution, but I get the feeling this is not the intended way to calculate it.

Comment: It seems to make little sense to use the whole series, given that $x\rightarrow0$, other than doing some contrived math acrobatics just for the sake of it..

Answer (score 0):

Let $ x $ be a real from $ \mathbb{R}^{*} \cdot $

Since $ \sin{x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}} $, we get that $ \frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{3}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{\left(2n+3\right)!}}=\frac{1}{6}+x^{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{x^{2n-2}}{\left(2n+3\right)!}}\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}\frac{1}{6} \cdot $

Which means \begin{aligned} \lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\frac{1}{\sin{x}}-\frac{1}{x}\right)}&=\lim_{x\to 0}{x\left(\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{3}}\right)\left(\frac{x}{\sin{x}}\right)}\\ &=0\times\frac{1}{6}\times 1\\ \lim_{x\to 0}{\left(\frac{1}{\sin{x}}-\frac{1}{x}\right)}&=0 \end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

For $x\to 0$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{x+O(x^3)}=\frac 1x\cdot\frac{1}{1+O(x^2)}=\frac 1x\left(1+O(x^2)\right)=\frac 1x+O(x)
\end{align}$$
Thus,
$$\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac 1x=O(x)\;\;(x\to 0) $$
and the desired limit is $0$.

Comment: What do you mean when you use "O"? I have never seen that notation before

Comment: It's called [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation. Have you seen solutions where series expansions are used? That's a very common way to write the remainder of the expansions.